# Select and manipulate particular paths within a path group fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

I am making an app that involves shapes like cylinders and boxes, and need to be able to do this with fabric.js. I know about three.js but for my purposes, it must be in 2D.

Initially I thought I would just create them in 3D software and render images which can then be added to the canvas, which I did successfully...

[image]

However, I have run into a hurdle where fabric only allows patterns to be filled onto paths or objects (rect, circle etc.)....not images (png).

Since I absolutely need patterns, I now need to create these cylinders in SVG. I have gotten as far as making the cylinders in Illustrator, saving them as SVG's and then using them on the canvas, then adding fill patterns on them. So far so good.

Now I want to be able to fill a different pattern for the top of the cylinder, and a different pattern to the side BUT still have it as one object.

**So...How can I select and manipulate particular paths within a path group? Is there anyway to give each path within the group a custom attribute (eg. name) which I can then target? Do I need to create two seperate SVG files and then add them seperately, and if so, how can I do this and still have it as one object?**

Here's how I am adding the svg to the canvas...

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL("/shapes/50-250R.png", function(objects) {
  var oImg = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects);

  oImg.perPixelTargetFind = true;
  oImg.targetFindTolerance = 4;
  oImg.componentType = "Shape";
  oImg.lockUniScaling = true;
  oImg.lockScalingX = true;
  oImg.lockScalingY = true;
  oImg.setControlsVisibility({'tl': false, 'tr': false, 'bl': false, 'br': false});

  canvas.add(oImg);
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Here is how I am adding the pattern...

```
var textureIMG = new Image;
textureIMG.crossOrigin = "anonymous"; 
textureIMG.src = texture.image;

obj.setFill(); //For some reason, the fill doesn't happen without this line.

var pattern = new fabric.Pattern({
  source: textureIMG,
  repeat: 'repeat'
});

if (obj instanceof fabric.PathGroup) {
  obj.getObjects().forEach(function(o) {
    o.setFill(pattern);
  });
} else {
  obj.setFill(pattern);
}

canvas.renderAll();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to figure this out. Each path within the path group is stored in the 'paths' array of the object.

I can now add a pattern to the top of the cylinder using...

```
var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
obj.paths[0].fill = patternOne;
```

and to the sides using...

```
obj.paths[1].fill = patternTwo;
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying the same thing, however, the canvas is not updating to reflect the change. When I inspect the active object, the new fill is set correctly.

I made sure to call canvas.renderAll() and am out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Comment: See my code above where I have the line `obj.setFill();`, if I remove that line, then I had the same exact issue you just described. For some reason, that line fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Unfortunately I have been using setFill all along, no dice. The only workaround I have been able to use so far is to trigger window resize event twice to make the canvas render the changes:

`window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')); window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));`